# How can I load a local library in Brython?

Tags: python, flask, brython

***plot.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/css5.css">
    <title>Protein Structure Analyzer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/jquery/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/brython/Brython-3.11.1/brython.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/brython/Brython-3.11.1/brython_stdlib.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="brython()">
<div class="angry-grid">
    <div class="header-div">SURPASS Plots</div>
    <div class="plot-div"></div>
    <div class="form-div">
        <form></form>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-div">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/python">
from PersistanceUtils import *

energy_list, time_list = PersistanceUtils.get_plot_data2("{{unique_key}}")

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Debug***

```
brython.js:9479          GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/PersistanceUtils.py?v=1676882840703 404 (NOT FOUND)
brython.js:9484 Error 404 means that Python module PersistanceUtils was not found at url http://127.0.0.1:5000/PersistanceUtils.py
brython.js:9479          GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/PersistanceUtils/__init__.py?v=1676882840718 404 (NOT FOUND)
brython.js:9484 Error 404 means that Python module PersistanceUtils was not found at url http://127.0.0.1:5000/PersistanceUtils/__init__.py
brython.js:9479          GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/brython/Brython-3.11.1/Lib/site-packages/PersistanceUtils.py?v=1676882840737 404 (NOT FOUND)
brython.js:9484 Error 404 means that Python module PersistanceUtils was not found at url http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/brython/Brython-3.11.1/Lib/site-packages/PersistanceUtils.py
brython.js:9479          GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/brython/Brython-3.11.1/Lib/site-packages/PersistanceUtils/__init__.py?v=1676882840753 404 (NOT FOUND)
brython.js:9484 Error 404 means that Python module PersistanceUtils was not found at url http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/brython/Brython-3.11.1/Lib/site-packages/PersistanceUtils/__init__.py
brython.js:14320 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "http://127.0.0.1:5000/plot#__main__", line 1, in <module>
    from PersistanceUtils import *
ModuleNotFoundError: PersistanceUtils
```

There is a file named `PersistanceUtils.py` in the application root.  The Brython script is unable to load it.

How can I load it?

[image]

Comment: Does this mean that the file should be found at one of the URLs listed in the debug output? Have you tried to paste this URL in the browser to load it manually? What happened?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, The specified python file is one level above the `index.html` or `plot.html`.

Comment: This means `http://127.0.0.1:5000/PersistanceUtils.py` should be right? Have you tried it in browser?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, Check the directory structure.  `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` == `templates`

Comment: If you mean that `http://127.0.0.1:5000/PersistanceUtils.py` maps to file location `FrontEnd/templates/PersistanceUtils.py` what would be the right URL to retrieve the file?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, That is the question I don't know the answer to.

Comment: Then this is actually a question about flask and how to map the URL to the right file location on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your python files for Brython inside the static folder. Then you import them with a script tag, whereby an id attribute has to be specified.

```html
<script type="text/python" id="demo" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='demo.py') }}"></script>
```

In the import commando you now refer to the defined id of the module.

```html
<script type="text/python">
    from demo import *
    
    # Use your import here.
</script>
```